# Не включать символ во вхождение регулярному выражению

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

делаю парсер для калькулятора (выражения поступают через stdin)
Хочу парсить комплексные числа (которые имеют вид примерно 3+6i), паттерн такой r'-?\d*i([^a-zA-Z]|)', группа ([^a-zA-Z]|) нужна, потому что есть еще переменные, например 5ix?=, и такие значения должны парситься как переменные, только строки с одной i и не буквенным символом должны определяться как комплексные числа. Находятся такие группы отлично, но во вхождение также попадает не буквенный символ после i (например в примере 7i+98 во вхождение попадет 7i+). какой шаблон надо сделать, чтобы он реагировал на символы после i но не добавлял их во вхождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, решение вашей задачи можно сделать и с текущим паттерном, нужно просто добавить группу:

```
-?(\d*)i([^a-zA-Z]|)
```

А в коде уже извлекать первую группу как число перед i. (по крайней мере именно так я понял вашу задачу)
Если не прав, поправьте.

Comment: немного неправильно поняли, но ваш подход помог, спасибо
Вроде логично очень, а сам не допёр